# Creating a one time action within a hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a menu that I'd like to appear at full-width when the page loads and then contract after for a few seconds. I've done that successfully by assigning a `setTimeout` function to my `timer` variable:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('nav').animate({width: '100p'}, 600, 'swing');
}, 1500);
```

I'd also like to animate the width of my div on a hover event as follows:

```
$('nav').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(this).stop().animate({width: '100'}, 400, 'swing');

}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({width: '30"}, 400, 'swing');
});
```

My concern is overall optimization. Obviously once the timer is complete it will never reset but essentially the user will call that `clearTimeout` function **every time** they mouse-in to that div. I first thought to use the method, `one()` but didn't want to create a completely new action outside the `hover()` event I have setup now. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: If the `timeout` only happens once, just clear it right after the `animate` call executes.

Comment: The reason I have the `clearTimeout` inside the hover event was in the event that the user hovers over the menu before the timer ends, it clears the timeOut and goes back to just being a normal hover event. If I removed the timeout from the hover event then it would jump.

Answer (score 0):

I'd tackle this with a css solution. Note that there would be legacy browser issues with the transition animation.

```
nav{
    width:30px;
}
nav.initial-expand, nav:hover{
    width:100px;
    -webkit-transition: width .4s; /* Safari */
    transition: width .4s;
}
```

Remove `.initial-expand`

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('nav').removeClass('.initial-expand')
}, 1500);
```

Since either `.initial-expand` or `:hover` trigger the expanded look, the removal of the class won't matter if they're hovered.

Also, I'd recommend animating it on/off screen using position left/right rather than width, as making it narrower can cause text wrapping oddities.